# Google cloud, URL map (load balancing), reduce time for change to take effect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

As part of my Google Cloud load balancing, I am using [URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/url-map).

On a working setup, I noticed that changes to the URL map take a long time to take effect.

For example, if I change for a working URL map a *host*-value from "abc.example.com" to "def.example.com", abc.example.com will remain available for at least a few minutes, while it takes a least some minutes, until def.example.com is available (I am not using any caching).

Is there a way to decrease this time, until the change is propagated?

Comment: While I don't think there is a faster method, currently, of updating the GCLB, you may be able to architect your way over the problem. If the domains have the same suffix, as in all of them end with "example.com" - you could use '*.example.com' if they have the same backend, but these assumptions may be wrong for your case. Consider adding more details on your architecture, number of backends, number of hostnames and number IP addresses - etc. so a fitting solution could be found. Alternatively, ask GCP to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually really low replication timeframe (just few minutes as you said). It can take up to 24 hours to fully replicate (Through all the worldwide) . DNS does cache it by default so you are actually using. The DNS has a property called TTL (Time to live) that caches the value of your records. So you would need to narrow this window of time to force the DNS to replicate earlier.

In the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#propagation_of_changes) you can read more about it.

Comment: The question has to do with Google Cloud Load Balancing, not cloud DNS.

Comment: Is about the DNS resolution of those domains, that would point to the old IPs while he didn't activate caching.

Comment: Google Cloud Load Balancing does not control DNS, URL maps simply define how to route requests based on path and hostname to backends. See [overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview).